Mapped types distributivity
I came across the following typescript challenge:
https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/15260-hard-tree-path-array/README.md
Unable to figure out the solution myself I searched for the most popular solution:
type Path<T> = T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>
  ? {
      [P in keyof T]: [P, ...Path<T[P]>] | [P];
    }[keyof T]
  : never;

This works perfectly but it doesn't make sense to me. What troubles me here is that if we test the solution with an input like this:
type PathTest2 = Path<{ bar: { a: string }; baz: { b: number; c: number } }>;

we get this:
['bar'] | ['baz'] | ['bar', 'a'] | ['baz', 'b'] | ['baz', 'c']

...and I'm struggling to see how distributivity works after we get at this point:
{ baz: ['baz', ...['b'] | ['c']] | ['baz'] }

I'd get it if we passed a union to Path but that doesn't seems to be the case here. Any clues on what's going on?

The distributivity that matters here is because it's using a distributive object type as coined in ms/TS#47109. If you have F<K> then {[P in K]: F<P>}[K] will distribute F over unions in K. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

That's pretty close. As you already suggested if K is a union then it makes perfect sense that F distributes over that union K. My case is slight different though (I think): So if input is this: { bar: { a: string }; baz: { b: number; c: number } } then when the baz record is processed, we'll arrive to this: {baz: ['baz', ...Path<{b: number, c: number}>] | ['baz']} which leads to this: {baz: ['baz', ...['b']|['c']] | ['baz']} .
Now my question is how ['b']|['c'] distributes over the tuple to give us: { baz: ['baz', 'b'] | ['baz', 'c'] | 'baz' }. Would love a full anwer @jcalz!

Oh, sorry about that. Most type operators in TS are naturally distributive over unions. If you're asking how [X, ...([Y]|[Z])] becomes [X, Y] | [X, Z] then that's just how variadic tuples behave, as implemented in ms/TS#39094 (see the part saying "when the type argument for T is a union type"). Does that now fully address it?

aah! Thank you @jcalz! That's exactly what I was looking for! Definitely missed this one! Apologies if I wasn't clear enough earlier. If you don't mind please fill in a proper answer and I'll accept it so that this question remains on the record

Many (but not all) type operators in TypeScript are naturally distributive over unions, since many operations are naturally covariant (see Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript).
For example, indexed access types are distributive over unions in the key (e.g., T[K1 | K2] is T[K1] | T[K2]). There are also distributive conditional types.
It turns out that variadic tuple types are also distributive over unions in the array/tuple type being spread. So if you have [A, B, C, ...(T1 | T2), X, Y, Z], this is transformed into [A, B, C, ...T1, X, Y, Z] | [A, B, C, ...T2, X, Y, Z].  This is documented in microsoft/TypeScript#39094, the pull request that implemented variadic tuple types:

Instantiation of a tuple type with a variadic element ...T depends on the type argument provided for T [...]  When the type argument for T is a union type, the union is spread over the tuple type. For example, [A, ...T, B] instantiated with X | Y | Z as the type argument for T yields a union of instantiations of [A, ...T, B] with X, Y and Z as the type argument for T respectively.

So ['baz', ...['b'] | ['c']] is automatically transformed into ['baz', 'b'] | ['baz', 'c'].
